# What does として mean here?

Tags: grammar

> 警視庁は１２日、父親を鈍器のようなもので殴った**として**東京都中野区に住む少年を、傷害の疑いで逮捕した。

Tell me please, what does として mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is grammar tosite which follows nouns, but in this case you need to recognize this as to suru which may also follow verb phrases. Depending on context, it could mean "to assume that", but in this case it means "to consider ~" or "to view ~ as ~". This often simplifies to "for".

> On the 12th, the police department arrested a boy living in Nakano-ku, Tokyo on suspicion of injury **for** hitting his father with a blunt-like object.

Comment: I think the "on the assumption" definition works as well, if not better here.  "Under the assumption that he hit his father with a blunt object, the police arrested..."