# Use of として in these examples 「男とは追々仲良くやっていくとして」 「無事であったとして」

Tags: grammar

The speaker is talking about his new classmates on the first day of a new school year.

> 男とは追々仲良くやっていくとして、やはり気になるのは女子陣だ。
> Getting on good terms with the guys _____、 as expected, what I'm really interested in are the girls.

[What does として mean here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11230/what-does-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-mean-here)

"Under the assumption" that [男とは追々仲良くやっていく], doesn't really have the 逆接 feeling that makes [やはり気になるのは女子陣だ] intuitive to read. Furthermore "男とは追々仲良くやっていく" is a future development, where as "警視庁は１２日、父親を鈍器のようなもので殴ったとして" is referring an accusation about a past occurrence. I could see it making more sense if it were ...仲良くやっていけるとして as an assumption. But just ...仲良くやっていくとして doesn't really make sense.

[What does verb+とする mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/what-does-verb%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-mean)

According the answer in this link, [男とは追々仲良くやっていく] would be the "new action" but what is actually happening is that the speaker is going to focus on the girls instead of [男とは追々仲良くやっていく]. So i don't think it applies.

---

The speaker has just asked his partner to seal (封印) away an enemy that was just defeated, and his partner says that there is no point as the enemy used a self-destructive technique and will naturally wither away shortly (……いえ、封印は無意味です。魔力の過剰注入で限界に達しています。もうすぐ、その肉体も精神も消失します。)

> 無事であったとして、両方お断りなのは変わらん事だ。
> "under the assumption" that thing are all good now, both parties (speaker's partner and the enemy) refusing (the sealing procedure) means that nothing has changed!

This is also a bit unintuitive read, although I might be interpreting the 2nd half of the sentence wrong. Normally sealing away the enemy after defeating them would be the most "無事" (this was already done several times with other bosses), so this may be why sentence is going is hard to pinpoint.

How is として used in these instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

とする has many usages, so please do not mix them up.

> 男とは追々仲良くやっていくとして、やはり気になるのは女子陣だ。
>   So I'll get along well with boys later, but it's of course girls that I'm concerned with (now).

This として is simply "I will ～". It's used in the same way as とする in 私達は先に行くとするわ.

> 無事であったとして、両方お断りなのは変わらん事だ。

This として does mean "assuming (it's 無事)" or "even if (it's 無事)". I strongly feel the latter half of your translation is incorrect, but I have no idea what 両方 and お断り refer to from the given context.

Comment: regardless of what 両方お断り means, ~のは変わらん事だ means  "~  is something that has not changed " right?

Comment: @charu Literally speaking, yes. A loose translation would be "I will still reject both."