# Past + として used in a sentence instead present

Tags: conditionals

> 彼がうちの会社に来た理由を聞いたとして俺はどうする
> 返ってくるであろう答えも想像はつく

The character saw a friend at his company and now he's wondering why did he join? Did he do it for him?

I do know するとして is used for suppositions, but I don't understand why he used the past here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What’s the difference between \[v\] たとしても and just the plain ても](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/989/what-s-the-difference-between-v-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82-and-just-the-plain-%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82) / [How is this sentence "working" after として?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70655/5010)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is this sentence "working" after として?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70655/how-is-this-sentence-working-after-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the friend joined the company because of the speaker and this reason, if known, would be problematic to him.

It's similar to とすると and としたら. Literally としても without the も particle. Keep in mind that the て form gives the idea that the clause that follows is somehow a consequence of the first one, but not so strongly as としたら does. I translated it as "if" regardless, but you get the idea.

[CLAUSE NON-PAST] + とする -> To assume [CLAUSE NON-PAST] (meaning we don't know whether [CLAUSE NON-PAST] is true, but we regard it as true).

[CLAUSE PAST] + とする -> To make a hypothetical assumption about [CLAUSE PAST]  (meaning we do know that [CLAUSE PAST] didn't happen, but we presume it did)

I found this particularly confusing because [CLAUSE NON-PAST / PAST] とする is often translated as "If I were to [CLAUSE].." and many [CASE]とする can be written in both past and non-past.

> 彼がうちの会社に来た理由を聞いたとして俺はどうする 
> If I assume someone **had heard** the reason he joined our company, what should I do? / Assuming I **were to ask** him the reason...

Comment: Context I think here the 聞いた is either him hearing or him asking. He's afraid to find out the answer, since people already know they know each other.

Comment: Then it would be "Supposing I had asked him the reason he joined our company, what should I do?"

Comment: @0149234 That would be "(過去に)理由を聞いていたとして". In this context, I think this guy is thinking about the (small) possibility of asking it *in the future*.