# What function does として have in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I read the definition of 信用:

> 人の言動や物事を間違いないとして，受け入れること

I have looked around a bit and found [What does verb+とする mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/what-does-verb%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-mean) but it only covers "dictionary verb form + とする"

This one is after a negative «ない», so I wonder if they are different.

So far I understand the sentence as «to accept the word and «thing» of a person and do so with no doubts».

Comment: This seems closer with a non-dictionary plain form preceding として: [What does として mean here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11230/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment points out, this is the compound particle として, meaning something like "assume". Here is the entry given by A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar, page 518:

[image]

Page 519:

[image]

So here it means something like "to take the speech and conduct or other things **as the truth** and accept it"

Comment: Can you possibly expand on the を間違いない part? Rikaichamp says that 間違い means "mistake," ない apparently means "not." Together they looks like "no mistake," or "no doubt." And it says that the result is an expression or an い adjective, which it looks like. But it's strange to me to see a clause that ends with an adj. and has a direct object (を). Sentences with adjectives I saw usually ended with some form of "to be". Some even say that い in い adjectives is in fact ["to be"](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2022/04/i-copula.html). So... should I treat 間違いない as a verb? At least it acts like so.